# Error upgrading connection 10.96.0.1:443: I/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I run Helm list or if I try deploy the Helm chart, the below error occurs.

```
[root@mcmpmaster01 ~]# helm list
Error: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

Comment: Hello. Your question lacks a lot of information to properly diagnose the issue. Please provide information like: 1. How the cluster was created. 2. What CNI are you using. 3. How did you deploy your Helm. 4. What is your Helm version?

Answer (score 0):

This Error in general comes when the configuration of your **CNI** (Container Network interface) **Flannel or Calico** .. is not well configured. I propose that you redeploy your network pod and you could also change the **CIDR** to be sure that the problem is not coming from that.

Make sure that you have declared your cluster VMs in the /etc/hosts.

Hope that this answer would help you out! Else could you give us more details about your cluster configuration ?

Comment: sure thank you :) to do that I have read somewhere dismantle  and configuring cluster from scratch is not recommended like that. if you have URL which can tells how to do that would be great help

Answer (score 0):

you should try to change your `~/.kube/config` address to the accessiable address. 10.96.0.1 is the cluster internal address. for example change to public address:

```
server: https://106.14.153.231:443
```

hope this help you. the ip 106.14.153.231 would access from your PC.